# how to set seekbar progress set to zero if video is finished in android

Tags: android, video-streaming, media-player

i am new to android i want to develop application of video player in this video player i need to integrate seekbar. i was stuck in this scenario. the scenario is the seekbar seeking up to video length,at the end of the video(video is finished to play ) seekbar set to zero plz help me how can i implement this scenario.

i do not know how to implement

```
1)how to set seekbar seeking up to video length/duration
2)if video is fully played how to set seekbar in start position/initial position(before seeking video position)
3)how can i get video is fully played
```

please any one help me as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found these links may be they help you:

[How to play a video using videoview controlled by a seekBar or Progress bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834728/how-to-play-a-video-using-videoview-controlled-by-a-seekbar-or-progress-bar)

[How to use a Seekbar in android as a seekBar as well as a progressBar simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731354/how-to-use-a-seekbar-in-android-as-a-seekbar-as-well-as-a-progressbar-simultaneo)

[How can i change the position of a progressBar, after the duration of a videoView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769723/how-can-i-change-the-position-of-a-progressbar-after-the-duration-of-a-videovie)

```
package com.coderzheaven.pack;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoViewDemo extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                   setContentView(R.layout.main);
                   showVideo();
               }
            private void showVideo()
            {
                VideoView vd = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getApplication().getPackageName() +"/"+R.raw.asal);
                MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
                vd.setMediaController(mc);
                vd.setVideoURI(uri);
                vd.start();
                vd.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
//you can set seekbar position here with help of vd.seekTo(progress);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply  hamad: but i cannot get how to set initial position of seekbar after video played fully.can u please help me how to set seeekbar set to initial value after video fully played

Comment: have you applied this method to set the seek bar postition  seekBar.setProgress(0); @yogi

Comment: also try this  videoView.seekTo(progress); @yogi

Comment: it will work hamad but i need to know where i have to put this code. Actually i want to put this code to end of video played but i need to know when the video will end how can i calculate and where i put this code ;@hamad

Comment: oh.. setOnCompletionListener(MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener l)

Comment: set that oncompletion listner to video view and in this set videoView.seekto(progress)

Comment: could you please put some program for me@hamad

Comment: i have added some sample code for you..if it is what you need then mark this as answer.

Comment: @hamad...very very thanks hamad..it works great.now i want one more  help hamad..how to set seekbar seeking value up to video length

Comment: mark my solution as answer,and add point so that it can help others too!

Answer (score 1):

1)how to set seekbar seeking up to video length/duration

you can acheive this by using this code:

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()  {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {                         
                long duration = videoView.getDuration();
            }
        });
```

if this works mark this as answer for others help

Comment: if i will give like this seekbar cannot move.it is still in same place only hamad

Comment: visit this may be it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802645/in-android-how-to-get-the-progress-time-of-the-video-played-under-videoview